# Can't get my app to close when YES is hit on Close dialog

Tags: android

When the dialog box appears asking to close and "YES" is selected the app doesn't close but it looks like it does.  It looks like it might be closing the screen but not the actual app.  This is from the MainActivity.java.  Any ideas or recommendations?

```
private void showAlerExit() {
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                this);

        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to quit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                // button yes
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity
                                MainActivity.this.finish();

                            }
                        })
                // button no
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: `It looks like it might be closing the screen but not the actual app` What does this mean?  Note.  You don't "close" an Android app, any more than you would close a web page.  The user navigates away from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

The purpose of `moveTaskToBack`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html `moveTaskToBack(boolean true)` Move the task containing this activity to the back of the activity stack.